# Problem loading Az.Kusto 2.0.0 PowerShell Module from Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-explorer, kql

To automatically configure an Azure Data Explorer Database from our Azure DevOps Pipeline we use the PowerShell Module Az.Kusto.
The Function we use to execute a KQL Script is [New-AzKustoScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.kusto/new-azkustoscript?view=azps-6.0.0) which is only available in the latest Version of Az.Kusto, so we run the following Instruction as part of our PowerShell Script which later calls New-AzKustoScript:

```
Install-Module -Name Az.Kusto -RequiredVersion "2.0.0" -Force -Scope CurrentUser -AllowClobber
```

Locally on my development machine this works but when we run this script as part of an Azure DevOps Pipeline we get the following exception

```
2021-06-08T09:15:42.1278098Z $RuntimeException/   at System.Management.Automation.TypeOps.ResolveTypeName(ITypeName typeName, IScriptExtent errorPos)
2021-06-08T09:15:42.1413212Z    at System.Management.Automation.Language.Compiler.NewOutputTypeAttribute(AttributeAst ast)
2021-06-08T09:15:42.1462865Z    at System.Management.Automation.Language.Compiler.GetAttribute(AttributeAst attributeAst)
2021-06-08T09:15:42.1465059Z    at System.Management.Automation.Language.ScriptBlockAst.<System-Management-Automation-Language-IParameterMetadataProvider-GetScriptBlockAttributes>d__68.MoveNext()
2021-06-08T09:15:42.1466223Z    at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
2021-06-08T09:15:42.1485936Z    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
2021-06-08T09:15:42.1503023Z    at System.Management.Automation.CompiledScriptBlockData.InitializeMetadata()
2021-06-08T09:15:42.1633625Z    at Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.Kusto.Runtime.PowerShell.GetScriptCmdlet.<ProcessRecord>b__16_0(FunctionInfo fi)
2021-06-08T09:15:42.1635647Z    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
2021-06-08T09:15:42.1637257Z    at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
2021-06-08T09:15:42.1693162Z    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
2021-06-08T09:15:42.1719336Z    at Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.Kusto.Runtime.PowerShell.GetScriptCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
2021-06-08T09:15:43.3829832Z ##[error]Unable to find type [Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.Kusto.Models.Api202101.IOperation].
2021-06-08T09:15:43.5666125Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

Any help or hints will be greatly appreciated.

**Updates:**

- Unloading Az.Kusto before installation fails with error message
  "No modules were removed. Verify that the specification of modules to remove is correct and those modules exist in the runspace."
- I see that in the directory C:\Modules\az_5.7.0 a version 1.0.1 of Az.Kusto is installed.
- Additionally when i install Az.Kusto in Version 2.0.0, this version gets installed in C:\Users\VssAdministrator\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
- When i install Az.Kusto with Scope AllUsers the Module shows up under C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
- When i import the Module, either by specifying a Required Version or by passing -Name and the path (Import-Module -Name "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Az.Kusto\2.0.0\Az.Kusto.psm1" -Force -Global) i get the same error.
- The Module Az.Accounts is installed in the Directory C:\Modules\az_5.7.0 in Version 2.3.0
- We call New-AzKustoScript in a different PowerShell Script than the one we have the Install-Module and Import-Module calls in. Might this be an issue?

Comment: Make sure you're manually importing it after installing: `Import-Module Az.Kusto -RequiredVersion 2.0.0 -Force`

Comment: We did that but unfortunately the error stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After isolating the situation in a new empty DevOps Pipeline i found the root of the evil.

Before installing and importing Az.Kusto, where was this call that caused all the trouble:

```
Import-Module Az
```

After removing it, those calls succeeded

```
Install-Module -Name Az.Kusto -RequiredVersion "2.0.0" -Force -Scope CurrentUser
Import-Module Az.Kusto -RequiredVersion "2.0.0" -Force
```

Thus providing access to the New-AzKustoScript Cmdlet.

Answer (score 1):

Adding another step to the comment, try out:

```
# Unload existing version and reinstall without clobber - removing the module should remove overlaps
Remove-Module Az.Kusto
Install-Module -Name Az.Kusto -RequiredVersion "2.0.0" -Force -Scope CurrentUser
Import-Module Az.Kusto
```

One of the updates in version 2.0.0 was to require a slightly different version of Az.Accounts, so check this too:

```
RequiredModules = @(@{ModuleName = 'Az.Accounts'; ModuleVersion = '2.2.8'; })
```

Here's some troubleshooting steps for awkward powershell modules. Compare the output you get on azure to your dev machine after importing the module:

```
# Check the loaded module:
Get-Module Az.Kusto | FL Name,Version,Path,

# On your local, try finding the missing type and the dll loading it:
[Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.Kusto.Models.Api202101.IOperation]|fl Name,Module
```

You may be able to manually import whatever missing dll via `Import-Module /azure/module/path/to.dll`. Or, you may find that that dll cannot be imported due to some error that the overall `az.Kusto` module suppresses.

Either way, you may want to try contacting the module creators - version 2.0.0 is less than 3 weeks old and has some other known issues: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+kusto

Comment: Thank you for the hints! I documented the outcome and additional information in the original post.